# Rails: rake error "/gems/faker.."

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

With any "rake something" command I get this error

```
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/faker-1.7.0/bin/rake:17:in `<top (required)>'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/faker-1.7.0/bin/rake:17:in `load'
```

This error repeat multiple time.

Notes:

- this problem didn't happen before.
- the Faker gem isn't new
- The gem works fine in other places

Comment: could you post the full error message.

Comment: that is the full error message

Comment: What is your rakefile?

Comment: have the same problem after upgrading to faker 1.7.0. There is an issue on Github though: https://github.com/stympy/faker/issues/780

Comment: I used the gem ffaker instead